# Laravel 5.1 redirect()->back() not working

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5.1

I am building the following repository for file upload. I need to check the file size and if the validation fails, redirect back to the form with errors. But when the checkSize fails the redirection will not take place. What is the problem?

```
<?php
namespace app\Repositories;

class UploadFileRepository
{
    public $fileNames=[];
    protected $maxSize=2097152;
    public function upload($files){
        foreach ($files as $file){
            if(!empty($file)){
                $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $this->checkSize($file);
                $this->fileNames[]=$filename;
                $file->move(base_path().'/public/uploads/', $filename);
            }
        }
    }
    protected function checkSize($file){
        $fileSize=$file->getClientSize();
//        dd($fileSize);
        $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        if ($fileSize == 0) {
          return  redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([ $filename. ' is empty.']);
        } elseif ($fileSize > $this->maxSize) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([ $filename. ' is too large.']);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question could be: (1) Is `upload()` being called? and (2) Is the `foreach` loop or `if()` condition even running? There doesn't appear to be any fallback if there's an empty file array, or empty file...

Comment: You r repository shouldn't be redirecting anybody anywhere. That is solely up to your controller.

Comment: what is the error that its returning?

Comment: @HalfCrazed Yes, I'm injecting this class into my controller and the files can be uploaded. The  foreach and if() condition is running

Comment: @JosephSilber Then how can I separate the file size validation from my controller?

Comment: @MiharbiHernandez No error is returning.

Comment: Im working in something like that and it http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html help me a lote, in my case  isValid() and getMaxFilesize() were the solution to this validation

Comment: @AliErfani - two options: 1) call `checkSize` from your controller, and have it return a boolean. 2) throw an error, catch it in your controller and redirect.

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks a lot. Redirection is working in the controller

Comment: BTW, laravel also has a `back()` helper you can use directly. No need for `redirect()->back()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a response in your `upload` function (or whatever function your route is calling).
In your code, `checkSize` returns a response if there's an error, but `upload` doesn't returns it, so it just gets lost.

Here's what you can do:

```
class UploadFileRepository
{
    public $fileNames=[];
    protected $maxSize=2097152;

    public function upload($files){
        foreach ($files as $file){
            if(!empty($file)){
                $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();

                $error = '';
                if (!$this->checkSize($file, $error))
                    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([ $error ]);

                $this->fileNames[]=$filename;
                $file->move(base_path().'/public/uploads/', $filename);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function checkSize($file, &$error){
        $fileSize=$file->getClientSize();
        $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();

        if ($fileSize == 0) {
            $error = $filename . ' is empty.';
            return false;
        } elseif ($fileSize > $this->maxSize) {
            $error = $filename . ' is too large.';
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your route calling UploadFileRepository@upload ? If it doesn't (it doesn't seem to), add `return upload($files);` in the function your route is calling.

Comment: No, I'm calling the upload method in my controller

Comment: Well, as I said, your controller needs to return `redirect()->back()` if upload() has an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your can try :  return back()->with('error','Error message');